# Phenolphthalein and methyl orange end points comparison

Tags: titration

In determining the solubility constant for Ca(OH)2, how does phenolphthalein end point compare with the methyl orange end points?

Comment: See wikipedia article on [pH indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator#Application).

Answer (score 2):

The suitability of indicators is given not only by their range, but also by the direction of the transition.

Generally, the transition is always much better from the light colour to the more intense colour, as the equivalence point and it's approaching is much easier to track.

So for MO (red 3.1- yellow 4.4), it is toward acidic, for PHPH (8.2 clear -10.0 violet/magenta), it is toward alkaline.

Both indicator ranges are about equally suitable for strong acid strong base titrations.

Usual issues with  $\ce{CO2}$, needing heating and cooling, do not apply in the case of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, due insolubility of $\ce{CaCO3}$.

As $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ is supposed titrated by an acid, I see MO with transition yellow to read as a better candidate than PHPH with violet to clear.